# How can I comment multiple lines on NeoVim?

Tags: neovim

On Vim, when I want to comment multiple lines I always use the following procedure:

```
1. select the first caracter of your block
2. press Ctrl+V ( this is rectangular visual selection mode)
3. type j for each line more you want to be commented
4. type Shift-i (like I for "insert at start")
5. type // (or # or " or ...)
6. you will see the modification appearing only on the first line
7. IMPORTANT LAST STEP: type Esc key, and there you see the added character appear on all lines
```

This works fine on Vim. However, on NeoVim it doesn't work at all... Can I comment multiple lines on NeoVim without using any specific plugin for that?

Comment: This is fundamental functionality that Neovim absolutely implements. You may need to debug your vimrc/plugins: [How do I debug my vimrc file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003)

Comment: @BLayer Thanks, you're right, it works on NeoVim. I had a problem on my `init.vim` file from NeoVim, I found a line with `inoremap <Esc> <Nop>`... Taking it out solved the problem. However, the command `nvim -u NONE -U NONE -N file` didn't work for initializing NeoVim without any configuration... I think the syntax is different in this case...

Comment: How about [`--clean`](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/31599/11054) (click that) as noted at the end of the linked answer (that I just added yesterday)? That's basically `-u NONE -i NONE` plus additional sterilization. It'll also tell you why you don't have/need Vim's `-N` (which essentially does `:set nocompatible`).

Comment: @BLayer Cool, both `nvim -u NONE -i NONE file` and `nvim --clean file` work fine for testing nvim without the configurations.

Comment: @raylight let's move the answer into an answer that you can accept :)

Comment: Also, you might find [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9549729/vim-insert-the-same-characters-across-multiple-lines/9549771#9549771) this one useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated in the comments, this functionality is already implemented on NeoVim by default. The problem was because my `init.vim` file from NeoVim had the line `inoremap <Esc> <Nop>`, which was interfering on the functionality of accomplishing the `step 7` that I said on my question. Taking out this line from the configuration file solved the issue.

One way of debugging if the problem is with the configuration or not when this kind of problem happens can be found on [this answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/31599/32434) on "[How do I debug my vimrc file?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/32434)". Basically, we can open a file with `nvim -u NONE -i NONE randomFileName` or `nvim --clean randomFileName` for checking how Vim or Neovim behave without any additional configuration. So we can check if the problem is on the configuration file or if it's something else.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by pressing Esc twice.

Comment: I don't have the `inoremap` line in my init.vim or .vimrc file but I have the same problem, pressing Esc twice doesn't work for me either. anyone know why?